# Can I override libtool within xcode?

Tags: xcode

We're using a modified compiler from under xcode. Mostly this works. However, as part of the modification, the generated .o files are not ones that the standard apple tools recognise, and in particular libtool does not like them. The effect of this is that we can't seemingly support static libraries (ie. .a files).

Does anybody know how to override the libtool we use? Worse case then is that I could write a script that did the right thing. As it is, I can only see how to replace the compiler.

Comment: Not really an answer, but so far the only idea I've had has been to copy libtool to a new name and drop in a script which tries to distinguish between the different .o types before it decides what to do. Seems particularly hacky.

Answer (score 0):

FTR The only way I've managed to do so for now is to override the libtool under:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

copying the original to libtool.real and having a shell script that looks at the .o files past and works out what to do. The one extra issue I've noticed (affecting how you write the shell script) is that the "ranlib" operation recursively calls the same script, so you need to be careful and only do the modified operation when the parameters precicely match the basic case (I check for there being more than one .o file either directly or via a filelist).